# C++/ ofstream with only a string type

Tags: c++, ofstream

### Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

string nom_fich("data.dat");

ofstream fichier(nom_fich.c_str());
string name;
cout <<"The name is: "<< name ;
cin>>ws;
if (getline(cin, name)){
    fichier << name <<endl;
    } else {        
      cerr <<"Error!";  
}
fichier.close();

   return 0;
   }
```

---

Question: why if I enter a number instead of a string my program doesn't say me "Error!"  ?

EDIT: how can I attempt to my purpose ? I want that get an "Error!" when I enter a type that isn't a type string.

Comment: A number can be represented as a string, so `operator>>` takes the intuitive approach: it treats any sequence of non-blank characters as a string. This includes digits as well. Also, instead of creating a superfluous `nom_fich` variable, you could just write `ofstream fichier("data.dat");`.

Answer (score 4):

Because a number is a valid string.

Answer (score 2):

Numbers can be represented as strings, i.e. strings can contain digit characters. For example:

```
std::string my_string("42");
std::cout << my_string[0]; // prints 4
std::cout << my_string[1]; // prints 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't enter a number. You can enter a sequence of characters that can be interpreted as a number, but that sequence is still characters. Those characters arw what `getline` reads.

Comment: I often use the phrase "textual representation of a number".

Answer (score 0):

A number can be represented as a string, so `std::ifstream::operator >>` takes the intuitive approach: it treats any sequence of non-blank characters as a string. This includes decimal digits as well.

---

Unrelated, but instead of creating a superfluous `nom_fich` temporary variable for the name, you could just write `ofstream fichier("data.dat");`.

Comment: The OP uses `std::getline` rather than `operator>>`.

Answer (score 0):

Because the string `"123"` is just as valid as the string `"abc"`, or the string `"def999"`.

As for "how can I attempt to my purpose?", you'd have to explain to us what your purpose is because, by your own admission, your own code *does not describe that purpose* and therefore we cannot extract your purpose from it.

Answer (score 0):

Reading a number as a string will certainly work: the number is just represented as a sequence of characters. If you want the stream to attempt reading a number and fail if it doesn't get one, you'd use a different type to read, e.g.:

```
int number;
if (std::cin >> number) {
    std::cout << "ERROR: read a number: " << number << '\n';
}
else if (std::cin.clear(), std::getline(std::cin, name)) {
    std::cout << "read a name: " << name << '\n';
}
```

After the unsuccessful read of a number the stream's state is `clear()`ed and, instead, it is attempted to read a name. There is a subtle issue as the formatted input for an `int` will skip leading whitespace while `std::getline()` doesn't skip whitespace. If skipping leading whitespace is a problem just use the manipulator `std::noskipws` before trying to read an `int`.